# Set Background drawable and Background Color

Tags: android, android-layout, view, background, android-linearlayout

> I have a linear layout and a text view.
> I want to apply background color and corner radius to linear layout dynamically at the same time.
> I applied
> layoutLL.setBackgroundColor(color)
> but it didn't work.
> The drawable is overriding the color.
> How to set both at the same time?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutLL
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview
        android:text=“TEXT”
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
       
 <corners 
android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
 android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
    </shape>
```

Comment: Can you post your drawable XML?

Comment: I have added the xml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `solid` attribute to the drawable as follows:

```
<shape>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

If you don't know the color in advance to place it into the drawable XML, you can programmatically change it like this:

```
val bg = binding.layoutLL.background as GradientDrawable
bg.setColor(Color.BLUE)
```

This assumes that you define the drawable as the background to the *LinearLayout*. If the background is not defined, you can create the background like this:

```
val bgDrawable = GradientDrawable()
bgDrawable.setColor(Color.BLUE)
bgDrawable.cornerRadius = dpToPx(requireContext(), 7)
binding.layoutLL.background = bgDrawable
```